# Combinations With Numbers as Phone Numbers

Tags: combinations

How many phone numbers are possible if you already have the area code (xxx-xxxx) if no zero is allowed in the first position?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I don't even know the first step or what the formula would be

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You have $7$ slots. In the first one, the only possible choices are $1-9$. In the last 6, the choices are $0-9$ for each slot.

Comment: 9 X 10 X 10 X 10 X 10 X 10 X 10 = 9,000,000?

Comment: @Jennifer Yeah that's correct